# Extract particular elements from an existing Collection and put it into a new Collection

Tags: java

I am using an API that returns a list like this:

```
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
```

Each item in `Object[]` is an array like this

```
Array[MyObject, String , String]
```

I want to get the first element of each array ('MyObject') and put them all in a new list

```
List<MyObject> myObjects.
```

I was wondering if there was a neat way of doing this using `Collections` class or something similar instead of an algorithmic solution?

Comment: Just loop through and extract/create what you want.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out to be a dumb question.  I like the java 8 solution by @Josh though

Comment: FYI, it is a really bad design smell to be using an `Object[]` like this.  You should have a class which actually contains a `MyObject` and two `String`s.

Comment: @Louis, it is not my API.  It is from Hibernate Envers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if I understand the question correctly, you could do something like this:

```
for(final Object[] result : results)
    myObjects.add((MyObject)result[0]);
```

Or if you are using Java 8, you could try something like this:

```
results.forEach(result -> myObjects.add((MyObject)result[0]));
```

Comment: When is the release date?

Comment: @user2310289 I'm a little unsure of the official release date, but you could get early access [here](https://jdk8.java.net/lambda/). I've been using Java 8 for quite some time now and I think it's pretty amazing. Although it reduces the number of lines, depending on what you're trying to do, lines can sometimes get a little long. But apart from that, It's great.